# Identity Server 4 - SSO with multiple tenants

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have several tenants that are defined by different URL using the same client

Client - c1

Tenants - t1, t2, t3

so, our users can access the client using different URL

http://t1.c1.com

http://t2.c1.com

http://t3.c1.com

Everything works wonderfull except when trying to single sign out.

[According to the docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html), we will use the field *FrontChannelLogoutUri* from Client to open a IFrame to clear the cookies for that client.

If we set the *FrontChannelLogoutUri* for any of the domains above, the SSO works for **that** tenant, **but not for the others**

**Question:** How can we logout from any of the above tenants?

My idea was to manually delete **ALL** the cookies from all subdomains, so, using *FrontChannelLogoutUri* as http://c1.com/logout-confirm, therefore it would clear all the cookies in that domain/subdomain

```
 [HttpGet("logout-confirm")]
    public async Task LogoutConfirm()
    {
       foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
       {
          Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
       }
       HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    await
       HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

This works if we open a new tab with that URL (defined in the client table), but for some reason the IdentityServer does not open the IFrame with that URL upon executing sign out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see you've found the solution on github. Could you close this one then?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was make one domain the starting point for the logout via the FrontChanelLogoutUri, for example `http://t1.c1.com/logout` clear all cookies for that subdomain and return a redirect (302) to the next domain `http://t2.c1.com/logout` and continue till you've cleared all cookies from all domains.